# Why does the std::move() work in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove, value-categories

Following is the code snippet:

```
int i=0;
int&&k=std::move(i);
```

In c++ primer the move is

```
template <typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type &&move(T&& t)
{return static_cast<typename remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);}
```

As far as i know,this `std::move` template will deduct a function like

```
int&& move(int& t){return static_cast<int&&>(t);}
```

As a comparison and to elaborate my question,consider an example like this:

```
 int test(int k){k=66;return k;}
 int k;
 int a=test(k);
```

The code above will be compiled as:

```
int temp;//the temporary object
temp=k;
int a=temp;
```

Similarly,i think the first code snippet will be compiled as:

```
int&& temp=0;
int&& k=temp;//oop!temp is an lvalue!
```

**which seems wrong because `temp` is an lvalue,did i get something wrong?**

Comment: I'm just curious, is there a special reason you ask this? Is it curiosity? Or is there some underlying problem with code you have that lead to this question? If the latter, perhaps it would be better to ask about that issue directly instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I've rectified.

Comment: Your first snippet is equivalent to `int &&k = static_cast<int&&>(i);`.

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast.  It will cast an lvalue or rvalue to an rvalue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No exact issue,i come across the question in the process of learning rvalue reference.

Comment: An rvalue reference is not necessarily an rvalue itself.

Answer (score 4):

> Similarly,i think the first code snippet will be compiled as:
>
> ```
> int&& temp=0;
> int&& k=temp;//oop!temp is an lvalue!
> ```

You might be confusing *type* with [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category*.

`int&&k=std::move(i);` and `int&& k=temp;` are not identical. The return type of [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is rvalue-reference and then what `std::move` returns is an rvalue (more precisely it's an xvalue), which could be bound to rvalue-reference. On the other hand `temp` is a named variable then it's always an lvalue, regardless of whether its type is `int`, `int&`, `int&&` etc. Lvalue can't be bound to rvalue-reference.

More infomations about [lvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue):

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, ...

and [xvalue(rvalue)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue):

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;
> - ...
> - a cast expression to rvalue reference to object type, such as `static_cast<char&&>(x)`;

Comment: @user9396941 It's an xvalue, which belongs to rvalues. And see my edited answer.

Comment: Seems peculiar to me.A value type of function is not equivalent to the return type of function?Does the c++ standard make this concept for `move()` specially to make move semantic legal?Or are there more examples of this?

Comment: or because the `int&& temp` ,temp is rvalue because it's a temporary object?

Comment: @user9396941 Type and value category are different things. The return type of the function is `int`, what the function returns is a prvalue; similarly, `int&` => lvalue, `int&&` => xvalue. Same for the named variable `temp`, its type is `int&&`, and it's an lvalue. A named variable is always an lvalue, regardless of whether its type is `int`, `int&`, `int&&`, etc.

Comment: @user9396941 i think it's because the `int temp` is actually a rvalue.

Comment: @bigxiao Variables are not rvalues. Variables do not have value categories. Only *expressions* have value categories.

Comment: A variable can be an xvalue if the form is `m.a`, where `m` is an xvalue, then `a` is also an xvalue. E.g. `struct S { int i; } s; std::move(s).i`, where `i` is an xvalue.

Comment: @Sneftel Your statement is only half right.A variable also belongs to expressions.Expressions consist of one or more operands.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi That's the expression, not the variable.

Comment: @bigxiao I don't know what you mean by "a variable also belongs to expressions".

Comment: @Sneftel like `int i`,`i` can be called as expression

Comment: That's a good point, and in that case the type of the variable influences the value category of the expression.